# Create Sharepoint List which has gantt view - programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, list, wss, gantt-chart

I am new to Sharepoint therefore don't know much - any help would be highly appreciated.

Basically I want to programatically (in the same project):

1. Create a List and make it a Gantt View
2. Add add appropriate columns (that would generate the Gantt chart) to the list
3. And finally I would like to add values/data to the columns created via this code

If there is a sample code or any tutorial...please

Any help would be much appreciated please

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yoursite/"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        Guid id = web.Lists.Add("listname", "descr", // 1
                                 SPListTemplateType.GanttTasks);

        SPList list = web.Lists[id]; // 2
        list.Fields.Add("display name", SPFieldType.Text, false);
        list.Update();

        // You should use "InternalName" to update your field values
        foreach (SPField field in list.Fields)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", field.InternalName, field.Title);
        }

        SPListItem item = list.Items.Add(); // 3
        item["display name"] = "my value";
        item["PercentComplete"] = 1; // 100%
        item["StartDate"] = DateTime.Now;
        item["DueDate"] = new DateTime(2009, 12, 31);
        item.Update();

        Guid itemId = item.UniqueId;
        SPListItem itemUpdate = web.Lists["listname"].Items[itemId];
        itemUpdate["PercentComplete"] = .45; // 45%
        itemUpdate.Update();
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply...Will this show the list automatically as a gant chart?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I meant linking the gantt properties such as startdate, enddate ,etc...please?

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but when i add the other properties it does not work

i want to add the startdate, end date and other details as shown below

                    list.Update();        SPListItem item = list.Items.Add(); // 3  

                    item["Title"] = "TaskTest";
                    item["Task Status"] = "In Progress";
                    item["% Complete"] = 59;
                    item["Start Date"] = "10/10/2009";
                    item["Due Date"] = "25/10/102009"; 
                    item.Update();

Comment: superb! this works perfect - last one more favour please...i really appreciate...                     item["Start Date"] = 10/10/2009;      is not working for me.....how can i add the date do i have to use speech marks plsss??


thank you so much....god bless!

Comment: WORKS AMAZINGLY GREAT! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! YOU'VE BEEN VERY HELPFUL 

THANK YOU!!!

Comment: One last question....once the list has been created and i have added one record...if i want to add more records will i use Getlist instead of the Add? And also if i want to update the same values again? e.g you've set the % to 100 and for e.g. i wish to change it to 45? please

thank you!

Comment: i've created the new question as requested - can you please help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578361/update-sharepoint-list-item