# Programmatically insert a List as a webpart in a webpart page in WSS 3.0

Tags: sharepoint, moss, web-parts

I tried searching on the net to programmatically insert a List as a webpart in a webpart page but was not lucky enough.

Any thoughts or ideas how i could **Programmatically insert a List as a webpart in a webpart page**

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First add these using statements.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;
```

Then in your code

```
// First get the list
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://myserver");
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
SPList list = web.Lists["MyCustomlist"];

// Create a webpart
ListViewWebPart wp = new ListViewWebPart();
wp.ZoneID = "Top";   // Replace this ith the correct zone on your page.
wp.ListName = list.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
wp.ViewGuid = list.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();

// Get the web part collection
SPWebPartCollection coll = 
    web.GetWebPartCollection("default.aspx",    // replace this with the correct page.
    Storage.Shared);

// Add the web part
coll.Add(wp);
```

If you want to use a custom view, try playing with this:

```
SPView view = list.GetUncustomizedViewByBaseViewId(0);
wp.ListViewXml = view.HtmlSchemaXml;
```

Hope it helps,
W0ut

Comment: any idea about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595915/create-a-dropdown-box-containing-list-documents-with-links-to-them please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform two steps to add a web part to a page. First you have to create the list you want to show on the page. Therefore you can use the Add() method of the web site's list collection ([SPListCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistcollection.aspx)).

To show the list on the web part page you have to add a [ListViewWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.listviewwebpart.aspx) to the web part page using the [SPLimitedWebPartManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager.aspx) of the page.

Comment: Thanks Flo! have u got any example or sample please?

Answer (score 1):

To make this more re-usable as part of a feature receiver, you could pass in the splist and spview as part of a method:

```
static public void AddEventsListViewWebPart(PublishingPage page, string webPartZoneId, int zoneIndex, string webPartTitle, PartChromeType webPartChromeType, string listName, string viewname)
{
     using (SPLimitedWebPartManager wpManager = page.ListItem.File.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
     {
         SPWeb web = page.PublishingWeb.Web;
         SPList myList = web.Lists.TryGetList(listName);
         using (XsltListViewWebPart lvwp = new XsltListViewWebPart())
         {
             lvwp.ListName = myList.ID.ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant();
             lvwp.Title = webPartTitle;
             // Specify the view
             SPView view = myList.Views[viewname];
             lvwp.ViewGuid = view.ID.ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant();
             lvwp.TitleUrl = view.Url;
             lvwp.Toolbar = "None";
             lvwp.ChromeType = webPartChromeType;
             wpManager.AddWebPart(lvwp, webPartZoneId, zoneIndex);
         }
     }
}
```

And then call it during feature activation:

```
AddEventsListViewWebPart(welcomePage, "Right", 1, "Events", PartChromeType.TitleOnly, "Events", "Calendar");
```