# ASPX to create, read, update, delete SharePoint List

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2007, crud, sharepoint-list

I notice a code inside the link - [Update Sharepoint List Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578361/update-sharepoint-list-item) can update the SharePoint List. However, I could not find much information on the following matters:

[1] ASPX code to perform reading of items (based on a criteria) inside SharePoint List. (This include deletion of its parent or children items if it is a lookup field)

[2] ASPX code to perform creating item(s) in SharePoint List.

[3] ASPX code to perform delete of items (based on a criteria) inside SharePoint List.

[4] How to create the above ASPX code (is it inside Visual Studio > ASP.NET Web Application or I can just create a single ASPX file using a notepad)?

[5] Do I need to import SharePoint.dll and what are the steps in creating such web application?

Thanks.

Wilson

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create / update sharepoint content from a site that lives outside of the SharePoint environment you need to work with the web services.

Here's some more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Also, here is a link to a blog post that I wrote related to propagating information from Dynamics CRM to SharePoint.  You may gain some value from the SharePoint aspects of the code sample...

http://glennferrie.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/crm-pulse/

Comment: Thanks GleenFerrieLive for your reply. As I am currently a beginner in SharePoint, may I know if there are any walk through or guides for beginner?