# How do I update a sharepoint list using .net?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a SharePoint list already created. I would like to occassionally update that list using a .NET application. How would I do that?

EDIT: This has to run on remote machines.

Answer (score 3):

pgb's answer is correct.  It's pretty simple, really.  One caveat with this is that the code that uses the SharePoint object model must be running on the SharePoint server itself -- not a remote machine. If you're trying to interact with a SharePoint list remotely, you would probably want to use web services.  SharePoint 2007 has decent coverage of list manipulation in its built-in web services, but if you want more specific functionality you can always roll your own.

A good starting point for the roll-your-own option is here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx

The SDK docs for the Lists web service can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately running on the server isn't a viable option. Do you have more info one the built-in web services?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have your siteId and webId you can do something like this:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId))
{
    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webId);
    SPList list = web.Lists["ListName"];

    // Manipulate your SPList here
}
```

Comment: I think you would also want to use `using` around the `OpenWeb` call.

Answer (score 2):

Please, look this questions:

- [Update Sharepoint List Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578361/update-sharepoint-list-item/1578509#1578509)
- [Create Sharepoint List which has gantt view - programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572528/create-sharepoint-list-which-has-gantt-view-programmatically/1572666#1572666)